# Why with FirefoxProfile script window.open() open new window instead tab?

Tags: selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I had a very strange issue: for the open new tab(not a window) in Firefox thougth Selenium I use:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");
```

And this worked ok, but when I added `FirefoxProfile` for `FirefoxOptions` like this:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("media.peerconnection.enabled", false);
options.setProfile(profile);
```

And instead of new Tab in the same window `.executeScript("window.open()");` open all in new window. But I need both things new tab for `window.open()` script and set `media.peerconnection.enabled` to `false`.

How can this happen why JS behavior depending on the profile?

How can I fix this?
I mean set media.peerconnection.enabled without a profile or prevent change JS behavior with Profile.

Comment: Question heading says `crashed`, question body says `open all in new window`, you mentioned about `executeScript("window.open()")` which opens a new Tab which is again equivalent to a new window. What are your exact _Manual Steps_. Update the question with your code trials.

Comment: @DebanjanB I mean crashed business logic